# Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function, React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, return-value, arrow-functions, array.prototype.map

I am making a search component in react and cant figure out this Error? i think its probably jus syntax but I cant see it.

src/components/SearchResults.js
Line 38:22:  Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return

```
 const filterData = () => {
    return data
      .filter((item) => {
        if (searchTerm === "") {
        } else {
          let searchText = item.title;
          let searchBlock = item.content;
          if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            return item;
          } else {
            let test = null;
            searchBlock.forEach((obj) => {
              if (obj.text && 
                obj.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                test = true;
                return test;
              }
            });
            if (test) {
              return item;
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.index}>
            <h3 style={{ padding: "0.25rem" }}>{splitResult(item.title)}</h3>
            {item.content.map((block, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
                {block.text && <div>{splitResult(block.text)}</div>}
                {block.items && (
                  <div>
                    {block.items.map((l, i) => (
                      <div style={{ padding: "0.25rem" }} key={i}>
                        {splitResult(l)}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
            <div
              className={styles.searchLink}
              onClick={() => {
                context.setCurrentSlide(item.index);
                setSearchTerm("");
                hideResults();
                clearInput();
                toggleSearch();
              }}
            >
              Go To This Slide
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      });
  };
```

Comment: Try to have return in every way possible. For example here `if (searchTerm === "") {
        } else {` in the if there is not return, so try to add it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `filter` method wrong. It accepts a function as a parameter and that function should always return boolean.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Your code is returning object (truthy) in some cases and in other cases it's returning undefined.

Here is your code with some comments to show you what's going on:

```
.filter((item) => {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      // returning undefined
    } else {
      let searchText = item.title;
      let searchBlock = item.content;
      if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return item; // would be better to do: return true;
      } else {
        let test = null;
        searchBlock.forEach((obj) => {
          if (obj.text && 
            obj.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            test = true; 
            return test; // unnecessary 
          } 
        });
        if (test) {
          return item; // would be better to return true;
        }
        // returning undefined;
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is another way of doing it (not tested):

```
 .filter((item) => {
    if (searchTerm === "") return false; // searchTerm is in scope?

    let searchText = item.title;
    let searchBlock = item.content;
    if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    } 

    let test = false;
    searchBlock.forEach((obj) => {
      if (obj.text && 
        obj.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        test = true;
      }
    });

    return test;
})
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you both answers helped i appreciate the time in writing th code too

Answer (score 2):

The first condition in your .filter() is missing a return statement.

```
const filterData = () => {
    return data
      .filter((item) => {
        if (searchTerm === "") 
        {
            // RETURN VALUE HERE
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
          let searchText = item.title;
          let searchBlock = item.content;
          if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) 
          {
            return item;
          } 
          else 
          {
            let test = null;
            searchBlock.forEach((obj) => {
              if (obj.text && obj.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) 
              {
                test = true;
                return test;
              }
            });
            if (test) 
            {
              return item;
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.index}>
            <h3 style={{ padding: "0.25rem" }}>{splitResult(item.title)}</h3>
            {item.content.map((block, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
                {block.text && <div>{splitResult(block.text)}</div>}
                {block.items && (
                  <div>
                    {block.items.map((l, i) => (
                      <div style={{ padding: "0.25rem" }} key={i}>
                        {splitResult(l)}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
            <div
              className={styles.searchLink}
              onClick={() => {
                context.setCurrentSlide(item.index);
                setSearchTerm("");
                hideResults();
                clearInput();
                toggleSearch();
              }}
            >
              Go To This Slide
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      });
  };
```